# Rails : Failed to build gem native extension with latest update (osx 10.9.2 + dev tools)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, gcc, rvm, bundle

**My environnement :**

- Mac OSX 10.9.2 (updated on march 20th)
- Xcode Version 5.1 (5B130a) (updated on march 20th)
- Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - March 2014 (from developer.apple.com website, downloaded and installed on march 21st)
- `brew install apple-gcc42` (already installed)
- RVM and ruby 1.8.7

**Problems :**

- When `bundle install` => "**Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**"
- When `xcode-select --install` => "**Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server**"

Any idea ?

Comment: The message "Failed to build gem native extension." related to some specified gem. Provide more information about Gem, you can not build.

Comment: The gem that I can't build is therubyracer. I uninstalled all versions of libv8 and right now, I get this message after gem install therubyracer :

Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. @Vitalyp